# Postgresql 9.1 Out of Memory During Create Table as .. Select

Tags: postgresql

I am on Ubuntu Linux 11 and Postgresql 9.1. I use CREATE TABLE .. SELECT over a dblink, and with a table of around 2 million rows I get

```
ERROR:  out of memory
DETAIL:  Failed on request of size 432.
```

So I am taking contents of an entire table from one database, and inserting (or creating them) inside another database (on the same machine). I am using default values of Postgresql, however I experimented with values from pgtune as well to no avail. During the insert I do see memory usage going up, however the error occurs before my machine's limit is reached. ulimit -a says

```
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 30865
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 30865
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

If I do create table as ... select inside the same database, then it works without problems. Any ideas?

Edit:  I tried adjusting the various memory settings in the postgresql.conf and it didn't help.  What am I missing?

Comment: Are you running with autocommit enabled? If yes, try turning it off.

Comment: I tried it didnt work. I found this link http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/populate.html with suggestions for large inserts

Comment: This gave me an idea -- I might be better off with pg_dump and working off a file.

Comment: Are you using the default postgresql.conf file that comes with Postgres? Can you try changing the memory allocated? By default,its something like 32 MB or so! Have you tried using the 'COPY' command?

Comment: I played with a lot settings in the postgresql.conf. None of them seemed to work. I already changed the implementation now, I only use pg_dump right now. Faster and more reliable. It also includes all necessary set, analyze, .. commands as well.

Comment: I know that explain analyse won't give you the related info but can you post just the explain output?

Comment: Also how big are these rows?

Answer (score 0):

My guess from this is that intermediate sets are being allocated to memory only and cannot be materialized per se.  Your best options are to find a workaround or work with the dblink people to correct this problem.  Some potential workarounds are:

1. Creating a csv file with COPY and insert that into your db.
2. Chunking the query to say, 100k rows at a time.

To be clear, my guess would be that dblink handles things by allocating  a result set, allocating memory required, and handing the data on to Postgresql.  It is possible this might be done in a way that lets requests be proxied over quickly (and transferred over the network connection) when they might not be allocated entirely in memory in the dblink module itself.

However for `INSERT ... SELECT` it may be allocating the entire result set in memory first, and then trying to process it and insert it into the table at once.

However this is a gut feeling without a detailed review of the code (I did open dblink.c and scanned it quickly).  You have to remember here that PostgreSQL is acting simultaneously as the db client to the other server and as a db server itself, so the memory gotchas both of libpq and in the backend will come together.

Edit:  after a little more review it looks like this is mostly right.  dblink uses cursors internally.  My guess is everything is being fetched from the cursor before insert so it can have a go at it at once.

Comment: My gut feeling is that this is a direct consequence of the two-phase commit, needed by the connection to the external DB.

Comment: I don't think so.  TPC doesn't depend on results being in memory.  More likely it is a result of dblink holding the records in memory as a result set (i.e. getting them all at once) and running out of memory doing anything with them.

Comment: added a longer explanation of what I think is happening.

Comment: I'll need to check the source. Could be it just uses something like the the old (*all-rows-buffered*) PQexec() interface.

Comment: I just checked again.  It looks like it uses cursors.  Makes me wonder if it is doing a FETCH ALL before the insert.